# breeze firstordefault query throws error

Tags: breeze

I have a web API which returns the firstordefault of a particular data model. If it returns a value then breeze is fine if it returns null breeze throws an error. The breeze query construct executeQuery(query).then(success).fail(failure) goes to the failure function indicating a server failure.The error is thrown on line 13627 of breeze.debug v 1.3.6 while trying to evaluate data.Results. Is this intentional or am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: Can you add an example of the server side query in question to your post?  We will try to repro.

Comment: @shai, we were able to reproduce the problem and it looks like a bug. We'll keep you posted.

Comment: This is now fixed on GitHub and will be part of the next release.